# Display first 100 characters from the table using echo

Tags: php, mysql, echo

Afternoon,

beautiful weather isn't it? Well anyways..

Here is my problem: (see photo) http://prntscr.com/7drmc5

ofcourse this isnt very user friendly, im trying to only display the first 100 characters of the field, with a break.

here is my code:

```
echo '<tbody>
<tr class="server glossed site">
<td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
'.$rank.'</td>
<td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
$row['description'].'</p></td>
<td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
</tr>
';
```

Thanks to anyone who gives this a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of [substr](http://php.net/substr) and you can also wrap it using [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
//it would wrap your text upto 20 characters 
$wrappedText = wordwrap(substr($row['description'], 0, 100), 20, "<br />\n", true);

echo '<tbody>
<tr class="server glossed site">
<td class="rank hidden-sm hidden-xs">
'.$rank.'</td>
<td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
$wrappedText.'</p></td>
<td class="votes hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.$row['votes'].'</td>
</tr>
';
```

Comment: What about making it break, so if say line 1 had a limit of 50 characters, it would break in to a second line

Comment: Ok, thanks again that worked out, there is still 1 big issue:  http://prntscr.com/7drr4l   see photo

Comment: again, the answer is wordwrap , it has an optional parameter `cut` with defaults to false, and you need to pass it as true - see updated in my answer

Comment: My up-most respect for you sir.  thank you very much!

Comment: Done :) have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr();`

```
$result = substr($myStr, 0, 100);//it will dispaly to firdt 100 charector from string
```

In code code it will be implement as

```
<td class="description"><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['name'].'<br /><p><a href="out.php?id='.$row['id'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['banner'].'" width="470" height="60"></a></p></a><br><p class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">'.
substr($row['description'],0,100).'</p></td>
```

As per your condition use

```
wordwrap($row['description'], 100, "\n", true);
```

Comment: What about making it break, so if say line 1 had a limit of 50 characters, it would break in to a second line

Comment: use css `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Ok, thanks again that worked out, there is still 1 big issue: http://prntscr.com/7drr4l see photo